# Can anyone tell me which LEGO set this is?

Tags: part-identification

My son was gifted some LEGO bags but with no instructions and I can’t find them on the internet.  It’s bag #4 and the only other number I can find in the bag is 135149. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [image]

Comment: A picture would help a lot.

Comment: Just added one:). I had to figure out how to reduce the size.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

- **Y-Wing Starfighter**, set 75172 from 2017

It comes in five bags.

[image]

Building instructions at [lego.com](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/75172)

Comment: I love how you included the bag to progress mapping in here.  That's a great idea for set-identification questions.

Comment: Oooh! I want the "snowmobile-with-outrigger-tracks-and-crane-plus-trailer" thing. :-)